# How to require a minimum CPU speed for an Android app

Tags: android, android-manifest, cpu-speed

I have written an Android app for signal processing that is computationally intensive. Certain algorithms that take a few seconds on a 2017 iPad take several minutes on an Acer B3-A40 (Android v7.0, 1.3GHz). I would like to limit the tablets and smartphones that can download my app if their CPU speed is too low. An Android CPU speed of at least 1.6GHz is needed. I measure the speed at loading time and warn the user if the computational response will be slow but I would prefer that the platform be excluded. Is there any way to express this limitation in either the AndroidManifest or the Android Device Console?

Comment: i doubt it, although it would be interesting to know if it's possible. one obvious option would be to go through the device catalog on the playstore and manually filter out lower end devices, but that doesn't really seem realistic or optimal